# How to select data between two dates in C# using ms access

Tags: c#, database, datetime, datagridview, report

i want to know how to select data between two dates i am using query but i get null data please help me
What I have tried:

```
DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dsa.Tables.Add(dt1);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Date],[Receipt No],[Delivery Person] from [Total] Where [Date] between " + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString() + " AND #" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#", VCON);
da.Fill(dt1);
```

Comment: Learn how to use parameters and your problem is solved.

Comment: please you tell me how to use parameters what's the mistake in my code please help me

Comment: The OleDbCommand (and all the DbCommand derived classes) has a Parameters property. This property collection contains a set of instances of the OleDbParameter class. Each instance here is used to transmit to the database engine a value to be used in the query. Together with the value, other informations are transmitted, like the DataType of the value. In this way you don't need to convert a DateTime to a string and the engine don't need to make the inverse conversion. This process is prone to conversion errors and thus it is a lot better to avoid it. Look at the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obviously difficult to say why you aren't retrieving any results without seeing the data you are querying against... e.g. is there actually any data between the two selected dates?

As a quick observation, you do seem to be missing a couple of "#" characters around the dateTimePicker2:

```
"SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Date],[Receipt No],[Delivery Person] from [Total] Where [Date] between #" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString() + "# AND #" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#"
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Steve said, you can use parameters like so :

```
DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dsa.Tables.Add(dt1);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Date],[Receipt No],[Delivery Person] from [Total] Where [Date] between @DateStart AND @DateEnd", VCON);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateStart", dateTimePicker2.Value);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEnd", dateTimePicker3.Value);
da.Fill(dt1);
```